# How can outgoing REST API requests be captured? (with request details)

Tags: networking

Are there any tools to capture outgoing REST API requests (HTTP) that can show the request details (headers, body, host)? I've been trying to do it with `httpry` and `tcpflow` but I can't get it to work. I'm sending API requests to the Amazon Web Services' APIs and the Google Cloud Platform APIs.